# Open many instances of child Browser in Phonegap

Tags: plugins, cordova, childbrowser

I'm checking on the possibilities of creating a browser app using phonegap. To launch a new window, I used the Child Browser plugin. 
Is it possible to open many instances of a child browser like how we can open many windows in our default mobile app? 
    
If so, can I switch over between the windows like a native app? Pls guide me regarding this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As referenced from [the README on GitHub](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser/blob/master/README.md), I'm not sure this is possible, as it denotes that it is a singleton.